# How to get all imageviews background color of recycler view items when user click on any imageview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The question may sound a bit unclear, sorry for that. Here is the complete explanation:

The items are below that line chart(colored imageview with text), now the functionality is when I click on any item(one items consists of one imageview and textview) then the imageview will become grey and the corresponding chart will get disappear from above, this I have done. But the problem is when I click on any other if any other item has already been greyed out then I don't get which one is already greyed out as I have implemented an onclick listener on holder.itemview from where I am getting the position of the current clicks. So now how do I check if any other imageview is already greyed out on any other item click.

MyAdapter class:

Updated Code:

```
class AdapterLegendsBusinessUnit(val items: List<String>, var adapterInterface: AdapterInterface) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterLegendsBusinessUnit.MyViewHolder>() {


    companion object {
        private var selectedItems = SparseBooleanArray()
        protected fun getColorID(position: Int): String {
            when (position) {
                0 -> return "#002581"
                1 -> return "#7cc576"
                2 -> return "#f69679"
                3 -> return "#f6c345"
                4 -> return "#1cbbb4"
                5 -> return "#00aeef"
                6 -> return "#0072bc"
            }
            return "#002581"
        }
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        fun bind(item: String) {
            itemView.legendName.text = item.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + item.substring(1).toLowerCase()
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(view: View?) {
            val wasSelected = selectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition(), false);
            val currentState = !wasSelected
            if (currentState) {
                view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.v1)?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"))
            } else {
                view?.v1?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getColorID(adapterPosition)))
            }
            selectedItems.put(getAdapterPosition(), currentState)

            Log.e("LEGEND Adapter", "my position: " + view)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder =
            MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.legend_recycler_layout, parent, false))


    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AdapterLegendsBusinessUnit.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
        holder.itemView.v1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getColorID(position)))

//        this.adapterInterface.foo2(items[position], selectedItems.get(position, false))
        val isSelected = selectedItems.get(position, false)
        Log.e("ADAPTER Legend: ", "Values of isSelected: "+isSelected.toString())

        if (isSelected) {
            Log.e("ADAPter legend: ", "Selected being called")
            this.adapterInterface.foo2(items[position], isSelected)
        } else { // Item is not selected
            Log.e("ADAPter legend: ", "Selected being called")
            this.adapterInterface.foo2(items[position], !isSelected)
        }

//        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
//            Log.e("LEGEND Adapter", it.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.legendName).text.toString()+ " :"+position)
//            it.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.v1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"))
//            this.adapterInterface.foo(it.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.legendName).text.toString(), position)
//        })
    }


}
```

Please help.

Comment: You should store a property name `isSelected` in the data itself. So whenever you click on view, just update this prop and call `notifyItemChanged`. Do not rely on view color for this purpose.

Comment: Can you show me some example? I have no idea about it

Comment: Or you mean per item one flag?

Comment: I added a way to archive this below. Please check if it can solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can archive this. Try one below

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    private static SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        boolean isSelected = selectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition(), false);
        if (isSelected) {
            // Item is selected
        } else {
            // Item is not selected
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean wasSelected = selectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition(), false);
            boolean currentState = !wasSelected
            if (currentState) {
                // Update view for selected state
            } else {    
                // Update view for deselected state
            }
            selectedItems.put(getAdapterPosition(), currentState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error selecteditems has not been initialized

Comment: that's working like a charm :) but can you please tell me how can i pass these events to my activity? i have updated the code above. As in my activity i have to filter out the dataset by using names only.

Comment: I have seen one issue, inBindViewHolder(...) isSelected conditions are not working or not calling even.

Comment: You could send `selectedItems` via your `adapterInterface` then you could do anything with that data in your activity. You could try to add some breakpoint to `onBindViewHolder` then debug your app to see what is going on

Comment: i think it will not get called without adding any listener in onBindViewHolder as that's the only way by which you can inform the onBindViewHolder to respond

Comment: I added the debugger at this line  val isSelected = selectedItems.get(position, false) and it says position 0, nothing else

Comment: So, it mean `onBindViewHolder` already triggered. what is the value of `selectedItems` and `isSelected`? If possible, please update your latest code with selectedItems.

Comment: When i launched the activity only then the logs get printed for isSelected and the value came out to be false for each item. But no logs are printing out when i click on any textview or on any of the item in that itemview.

Comment: In my example above, item is updated in viewholder when clicked. If you want onBindViewHolder to be trigger again, you have to call adapter.notify[*]

Comment: Well i have made it work by directly calling adapterInterface from ViewHolder onclick, is it still ok or a bad approach? I should call adapterInterface from onBindViewHolder only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204101/discussion-between-tuan-luong-and-sak).